# How to remove or change ASP.NET MVC 5 default cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, owin

I've created an `ASP.NET MVC 5` application with "Individual User Accounts" (OWIN). I'm following [this guide](http://arturito.net/2011/10/21/how-to-remove-server-x-aspnet-version-x-aspnetmvc-version-and-x-powered-by-from-the-response-header-in-iis7/) to remove unnecessary HTTP headers that exposes stuff I don't want to expose.

Everything was removed properly but there's one extra thing that's revealing this is an ASP.NET application which is the default cookie:

```
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=gpryojsaen2hnukmzoh5xbuv;
```

**Is there a way to change the name to something else?**

Comment: `app.UseExternalSignInCookie` or `app.UseCookieAuthentication` i believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I neded to add this to the `web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState cookieName="foo" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 3):

Given you're using OWIN, you should be able to change the setting in your `app.UseCookieAuthentication` call. Something like:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        CookieName = "ChangeMe",
        /* other options */
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped but the ASP.NET Session cookie was still there. I thought it had something to do with OWIN, but's not. It's the default ASP.NET session state cookie.

Comment: Ah, my misinterpretation and apologies. Glad you found it though. ;-)